# Array of pointers to strings not storing data as it should

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to store words from a text file in dynamically assigned arrays of chars. I am using pointer arrays to array of chars in order to allocate memory dynamically but for some reason it only stores the last input word to all the arrays of chars I am pointing to, even though in some places that strings should not fit as I allocated space for smaller strings.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char input_string[30];
    int string_length, text_length;

    // Calculating number of words in text file.
    text_length=0;
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    while (scanf("%s", &input_string)!=EOF) {
        text_length++;
    }
    freopen("CON", "r", stdin);

    // Dynamically assigning array of chars to store words
    char **pointer;
    int i;
    pointer=(char*)calloc(text_length, sizeof(char));
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    for  (i=0;i<text_length;++i) {
        scanf("%s", &input_string);
        string_length = strlen(input_string);
        pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length, sizeof(char));
        *(pointer+i)=input_string;
    }
    for (i=0;i<text_length;++i) {
        printf("%s ", *(pointer+i));
    }
    freopen("CON", "r", stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1)`pointer=(char*)calloc(text_length, sizeof(char));` --> `pointer=(char**)calloc(text_length, sizeof(char*));`

Comment: 2)`pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length, sizeof(char));` --> `pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length+1, sizeof(char));`

Comment: 3)`*(pointer+i)=input_string;` --> `memcpy(pointer[i], input_string, string_length);`

Comment: on this for (i=0;i<text_length;++i) {
            printf("%s ", pointer[i]);
    } it still writes out only the last word from the text file for some reason

Comment: Is not performed for the No.3 change. There is a need to copy the contents pointing,  its not a copy of the pointer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, may I know why the way I wrote the third command is not working? And also, if you can explain me the first two commands what I was doing wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: 1-1)type of `pointer` is `char**`. cast of `(char*)` wrong. 1-2) `sizeof(char)` isnot `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: 2) It is necessary to secure a size of string length + NUL terminated character.

Comment: this line, within a while loop: while (scanf("%s", &input_string)!=EOF) { will fail to read the successive words because there is no provision to skip over white space (' ', newline, etc)  the format string should be: " %s"  <-- notice the leading space in the format string

Comment: 3) Address of the array is constant, it is necessary to copy the contents that its retention.

Comment: the call: freopen("CON", "r", stdin); can fail for several different reasons.  Therefore, the return code must be checked to assure no error has occurred.

Comment: @user3629249 `%s` will skip the leading whitespace characters. You do not need to append a space.

Comment: this line: pointer=(char*)calloc(text_length, sizeof(char)); fails to allocate enough memory.  as it only allocates one byte for each word in the input file. it needs to allocate room for a char * (typically 4 bytes) * the number of works in the file.

Comment: this line: pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length, sizeof(char)); needs to allocate one more char to allow for the string terminator.

Comment: this line: *(pointer+i)=input_string; only passes a pointer to the buffer input_string, it does NOT actually save the string.  This is not what needs to be done.  THe pointer is already set to point to an allocated memory area.  so what needs to be done is copy the buffer'input_string' to the allocated area, perhaps by: strcat( *(pointer+i), input_string);

Comment: just before invoking 'return' all of those memory allocations need to be free'd, by passing each and every pointer value in the pointer array to free() the passing pointer to free()  otherwise a memory leak occurs, consuming resources.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: It is not a good adivse to cast the result of `calloc()`.

Comment: OT: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

*(pointer+i)=input_string

Here input_string is the array and it takes the string from the file. So in the above statement, you are overwriting address of pointer array(allocated memory) with the input string.

pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length, sizeof(char)); // alloacted memory

*(pointer+i)=input_string; //alloacted memory overwritten here pointer[i] and *(pointer+i) both both notifies same

So each index of the array has the same base address of input_string and while de-refer it will give the string which is present in the array(last string). This is the reason for your problem. Better you do memcpy or strcpy.

pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length, sizeof(char));
strcpy(pointer[i], input_string)

or

pointer[i]=(char*)calloc(string_length, sizeof(char));
memcpy(pointer[i], input_string, string_length));
*(*(pointer+i)+string_length)='\0'; /* assigning null character at end of string * /

Comment: It shall be `calloc(string_length + 1 ...` as C-"string"s have to be `0`-termninated. This `((pointer+i)+string_length)='\0';` writes past the end of the current array.

Comment: Also in C it isn't necessary, nor recommended to cast the result of `calloc/malloc/realloc`.